# Get a list of all scripts and their paths which are run as cron job

Tags: cron

I am looking for some script or terminal command to **list all the scripts** (preferably with their paths) which are run on a periodic basis by cron, cron.daily. I am not looking for any filter for time-period of the script and want all the scripts listed ( however some administrators may want this kind of filter).

**Purpose:** To document all scripts running periodically so that debugging or fault check , updating and transferring to a newer system is easy and efficient.

Comment: Simplistically you're asking what jobs are in cron; narrowed down to just scripts, not binaries? What about scripts that are subsequently *called* by those top-level scripts? That would be a bit more involved...

Comment: I am only only concerned about  the user scripts set as cron jobs.

Comment: Non-root users only?

Comment: Yeah, non root users only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the filenames and script types of all scripts run from cron by non-root users (does not identify user):

```sh
find /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ -type f ! -name 'root' \
  -exec awk '!/^[[:blank:]]*(#|$)/ {print $6}' {} + | 
    xargs -d'\n' file | grep -i script
/home/cas/scripts/fetch.sh:               Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
/usr/local/sbin/backup-postgres.sh:       Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

To find all executables (binaries & scripts) run from cron by non-root users (identifies user):

```sh
find /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ -type f ! -name 'root' \
  -execdir awk '!/^[[:blank:]]*(#|$)/ {print FILENAME"\t"$6}' {} + |
  sed -e 's:^./::'
cas   /home/cas/scripts/fetch.sh
postgres      /usr/local/sbin/backup-postgres.sh
```

Of course, both of these have to be run as root.  Only root can read the crontabs of all users.

Note: The crontabs may be in a different directory on your system.  Check the documentation for your cron daemon.